# LDAP: ldapadduser - can I add to two different groups?

Tags: ldap, openldap

Usually - `ldapadduser` assumes only one attribute for group-name:

```
 # ldapadduser sysuser2 sysusers
```

Can I add add this users in to two groups while creating user?

If I try run like:

```
# ldapadduser sysuser2 sysusers,wheel
Warning : using command-line passwords, ldapscripts may not be safe
Cannot resolve group sysusers,wheel to gid : not found
```

I got error...

If no - can I modify users after adding to make him member of two groups?

Using **FreeBSD** 9.1 and **OpenLDAP** 2.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ldapadduser` set the user primary group which is unique.

You should use `ldapaddusertogroup` for secondary ones.